# Express.js missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some code:

```
doc.image('images/pic_1.jpg', 0, 15, scale: 0.25)
    .text('Scale', 0, 0)
```

Based on official PDFkit documentation:
[PDFKit documentation](http://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html)
But, this didn't work, and node console show me this, error, and underline `scale:0.25` part:

```
doc.image('images/pic_1.jpg', 0, 15, scale: 0.25) SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to wrap `scale` into the object like

```
doc.image('images/pic_1.jpg', 0, 15, { scale: 0.25 })
    .text('Scale', 0, 0)
```